# Separate query results by "week of" in a custom post type (Wordpress/PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a Custom post type of "events" and I have a custom metabox for the date of the event. All events added with all dates recorded into database in srtotime() UNIX format.

When list of events is queried I need to separate them by week. So.. "week of 4/23" then list the events for that week only.. followed by "Week of 4/30" with the events for that week listed.

All of this needs to be dynamic and logically detect when each week begins and compare that to the date that is saved in the database for the returned events, thus grouping them into "weeks."

I hope that all makes sense. I am just having trouble finding resources for this type of functionality, and I am uncertain of the logic needed and what WP might already have I could use.
As of now the results are being pulled using a custom Wordpress loop, but I could use SQL if needed.

Thanks in advance for helping any way you can!

*UPDATED CODE

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'         => 'tf_events', 
'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
'orderby'           => 'meta_value', 
'meta_key'          => 'tf_events_startdate', 
'order'             => 'ASC'
));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($loop);
echo '</pre>';

$groups = array();

if ($loop->have_posts()) {
  while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();

    $groups['Week of ' . $post->post_date][] = $post;

// Get event dates from WP metabox data (returns as string) 
$longstartdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tf_events_startdate', true); //get start date meta data
$longenddate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tf_events_enddate', true); //get start date meta data
$longweekof = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tf_events_weekof', true); //get Week Of date meta data

// Reformat dates
$prettystartdate = date("D. M. j, Y", $longstartdate);
$prettyenddate = date("l, F j, Y", $longenddate); 
$prettyweekof = date("m/d", $longweekof);

// Get Custom Meta Terms/Catagories/taxonomies
$the_venue = get_the_term_list(  $post->ID, 'venue' );
$event_age = get_the_term_list(  $post->ID, 'event_age' );

// Get Custom Metabox Data - URL for Buy Tickets
$buytix = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'buytix', true );
 }
}
?>

<h1>Groups of posts</h1>
<?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($groups); echo '</pre>';?>
<?php foreach ($groups as $week => $rows) : ?>
<h2><?php echo $week ?></h2>

<ul>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>
    <?php echo ' <h1>POST START</h1> <pre>';
print_r($post);
echo '</pre> <h1>POST END</h1>'; ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a> <?php echo $prettystartdate; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: anyone able to help implement the solution below or another option? I am still stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is rough solution that is working for me.

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'         => 'tf_events', 
'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
'orderby'           => 'meta_value', 
'meta_key'          => 'tf_events_startdate', 
'order'             => 'ASC'
));

$groups = array();
$heading = '';
if ($loop->have_posts()) {
while ($loop->have_posts()) {
    $loop->the_post();

//set up pretty week
$weekof = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tf_events_weekof', true); //get Week Of date meta data
$longstartdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tf_events_startdate', true); //get start date meta data
$longenddate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tf_events_enddate', true); //get start date meta data

//format dates
$prettyweekof = date("m/d", $weekof);
$prettystartdate = date("D. M. j, Y", $longstartdate);
$prettyenddate = date("l, F j, Y", $longenddate); 

//set info on objects
$post->prettyweekof = $prettyweekof;
$post->pretty_startdate = $prettystartdate;
$post->pretty_enddate = $prettyenddate;

//Echo heading when need to
if($post->prettyweekof !== $heading)
{
$heading = $post->prettyweekof;
echo '<h2>'.$heading.'</h2>';

}

//list events
echo $post->post_title.' | '.$post->pretty_startdate.' - '.$post->pretty_enddate.'<br />';


}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to group elements I normally use an associative array where the key is the thing to group by. So in your case the array would look something like:

```
array(
    'Week of 4/30' => array(array of posts)
);
```

An easy way to do this (once you have all the posts) is like this:

```
$groups = array();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $groups['Week of ' . date('m/d', $post->pub_date)][] = $post;
}
```

And then you can just:

```
foreach ($groups as $title => $posts) {
     echo "<h2>$title</h2>";

     foreach ($posts as $post) ...
}
```

Edit: Here's what a more complete code (including WP query etc) would look:

```
<?php
# Get all posts
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'tf_events', 
    'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value', 
    'meta_key'          => 'tf_events_startdate', 
    'order'             => 'ASC'
));
$groups = array();

# Create groups of posts
if ($loop->have_posts) {
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();

        $groups['Week of ' . date('m/d', $post->tf_events_weekof)][] = $post;
    }
}
?>

<h1>Groups of posts</h1>

<?php foreach ($groups as $week => $rows) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $week ?></h2>

    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($rows as $post) : setup_postdata($post) ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: In your example it's using the published-on date, as far as I can tell, but what if I needed to use the actual date the event is taking place. 
Most events take place on Thursday, Friday or Saturday... but I need to list those broken down by "week of" which would be either the Sunday or Monday before the events take place.
What if I were to add another custom meta box for them to input the "week of" date and then group by _that_ date.

Comment: All you'd need to change is `$post->pub_date` to whatever other variable you wanna use.

Comment: I surely appreciate your help, I am obviously missing something on implementation of your method. Possibly that I am using $loop rather than $posts for my call or the initial if and while loops are conflicting with the foreach loops. I tried various changes that I though would possibly solve, but nothing helped. Please see my full code at this URL. [http://snipt.net/rellison959/testing-event-lists/](http://snipt.net/rellison959/testing-event-lists/)

See example page of loop here [http://www.6am-group.com/events_test/](http://www.6am-group.com/events_test/)

Comment: Yes, you have to first build the `$groups` array inside your `while` loop (without printing anything) and _then_ loop the `$groups` array and print the HTML. You're also trying to loop a `$posts` array which doesn't exist. Just remove that loop and keep only `    $groups['Week of ' . date('m/d', $post->tf_events_weekof)][] = $post`.

Comment: I am definitely lost now. Not sure I understand.

Comment: See updated answer. You had loops in loops in loops. That's not going to work.

Comment: THANK YOU so much for all this help! The arrays are full of objects, but my custom meta elements are not in the arrays as options so things are not working as expected. I have test page printing all arrays if you want to see. [http://www.6am-group.com/events_test/](http://www.6am-group.com/events_test/)